# I don't know if I am deploying right.. site doesn't work

Tags: python, django

So I have studied the book, how to tango with django 1.10 and I was trying to deploy here my project. The bash part worked perfectly, but when I deployed and I go to danielcirstea.pythonanywhere.com/rango the app doesn't show.This is my web configuration: https://i.stack.imgur.com/67S05.png I also changed DEBUG to FALSE and hosts as needed. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your project in production than keep `DEBUG = False` otherwise, first test in `DEBUG = True`

Also, allow all hosts `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` though this is very unsecure.

Run manage.py as `python manage.py runserver youip/domain:port`

Hope this works.